# How to make contains of React-QueryBuilder case insensitive?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, query-builder, react-query

Is there any way to format the output of React-QueryBuilder a case insensitive as default it comes with case sensitive while creating query.

I want make of certain default field as case insensitive. As default all the query output is case sensitive.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best solution but found a way around it. For my requirement I made it for Mongo you can adjust it as per your requirement.

here is a solution code:

```js
 const formatQueryToCaseInSensitive = (query, fieldToChange) => {
    
    if (Array.isArray(query.rules)) {
      const formatQuery = query.rules.map((item) => {
        if (Array.isArray(item?.rules)) {
          return formatQueryToCaseInSensitive(item, fieldToChange);
        } else if (fieldToChange.includes(item.operator)) {
          return { ...item, value: `(?i)${item.value}(?-i)` };
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      });
     return { ...query, rules: formatQuery };

    }
          };
```

You can call this function inside formatQuery:

```js
const submitHandler=()=>{
const mongoQuery = formatQuery(
      formatQueryToCaseInSensitive(query, ["contains","doesNotContain"]),
      "mongodb"
    );

}
```

This solution is for react. Hope this will find helpful